# any project about version control system

Tags: python, version-control

recently i opened a repository in github and after i saw other version control system on google but i wanted to know how they work and maybe do a small project on it because i am student in university and i searched online for free source code working like github or any other website but i didn't get them so if someone has  the simple project project that has the logic of a version controller or maybe tell me the login  behind them and  i can start working on it i use mostly python and java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- github is just a website. It doesn't do version control. Source code of github is not available.
- The actual version control of github is executed by open source software named `git`, written in C. Source code of git is here https://github.com/git/git
- gitlab is another website like github, but open source. Source code for gitlab is available here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce
- git is written in C, but there are other version control software written in python. One example is mercurial, source is here https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-all/

Comment: is it possible to have a simple project working like github or gitlab just to know the logic behind these website or git as you say

Comment: @christiannshimyumukiza yes, if you download gitlab source code, you can run it on your own machine. Instructions are in the page I linked.